# Android ActionBar overflow checkbox style

Tags: android, checkbox, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

In my app I have a custom drawable for checkboxes and it works through-out by default in the general interface areas, however it doesn't show up in the overflow menu when there is a checkable item, instead it shows the default holo checkbox!

[image]

*Here is an example of the custom checkbox*[image]

Here's how I've been able to style the overflow menu (was painfully hard), I'm looking for a style like this that will override the checkbox

```
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/pop_dark</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: No not yet unfortunately, I think the only solution would be to manually implement a popup menu, and have a custom list item. But that obviously is really time consuming across an entire project.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. If I figure it out I'll post back here.

Comment: As an off-topic side note - is there any reason why you stick to ActionBarSherlock and do not use ActionBarCompat?

Answer (score 4):

If you override `android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple` in your theme, it will apply to all checkboxes, those in your normal UI as well as those in in popup menus, i.e.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme...">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@style/YourCheckBoxStyle</item>
</style>
```

If you only want to theme the checkboxes in your ActionBar, then you can use `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` since API 14:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme...">
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/MyActionBarWidgetScheme</item>
</style>
...
<style name="ActionBarWidgetTheme" parent="android:Widget">
    <item name="android:listChoiceIndicatorMultiple">@drawable/YourCheckBoxStyle</item>
</style>
```

(Kudos to Daniel Lew [pointing that one out](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.de/2012/11/the-unknown-style-actionbarwidgettheme.html).)